# Spring Boot throws BeanCreationException on startup

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I have started migration a Spring MVC / Spring Web Tomcat App to Spring Boot.
Currently I am migrating the xml configuration files to java configuration.

When I try to start my application via mvn spring-boot:run I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.faz.osc.MultitenancyService net.faz.osc.MessageSource.multitenancyService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multitenancyServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest net.faz.osc.MultitenancyServiceImpl.request; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:468)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:958)
    at net.faz.osc.Application.main(Application.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:423)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private net.faz.osc.MultitenancyService net.faz.osc.MessageSource.multitenancyService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'multitenancyServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest net.faz.osc.MultitenancyServiceImpl.request; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

The code snippet causing the error is

```
@Service
public class MultitenancyServiceImpl implements MultitenancyService {

    public static final String MANDANT_KONNTE_NICHT_UEBER_SERVERNAMEN_ERKANNT_WERDEN = "Mandant konnte nicht über Servernamen erkannt werden.";

    @Value("#{'${server.names.faz}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> fazServerNames;

    @Value("#{'${server.names.rundschau}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> rundschauServerNames;

    @Value("${vkorg.faz}")
    private String fazVkorg;

    @Value("${vkorg.rundschau}")
    private String rundschauVkorg;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private HttpServletRequest request;

...
```

On researching the web I just found, that Autowiring the HttpServletRequest should always work fine...

Before migration to java based configuration the application worked fine as WAR file placed inside a tomcat.

Any hints what I am missing? If further information is required just tell me, I will provide relevant code.

KR
Habib

Comment: Can you paste in the Java Configuration files for Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `HttpServletRequest` is request scoped bean, you can only inject it into request object; example `@Controller` classes.

So move `@Autowired(required = true) private HttpServletRequest request;` to controller class and pass the reference to `@Service` classes through setter.

Comment: To complement this answer, I am guessing that you controlled the creation of that class before via some kind of XML configuration and now it's being picked up automatically by boot. Maybe you should disable component scanning? replace `@SpringBootApplication` by just `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

Comment: Hey, that's exactly how it worked before. Changed the annotation and now the app starts. But unfortunatly now I am getting a basic authentication request on loading a page instead of the normal page getting displayed. Any idea?

Comment: Hi, do you have link for this reference? @Lovababu that said Controller annoatation is request object class or you just read from the source code ? but anwy Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the required=true. Now it works.
Thanks for the tipps so far!

Comment: Have you setted to `@Autowired(required=false)` ? If yes, this might cause some NPE since Spring might not inject this for you, so is better to check for nulls

Comment: Strange, it defaults to true when not setted, but if works :D

Comment: hmmm I should read my own code more precisly... I didn't just remove the required attribute, I commented the whole Autowired annotation... Works as long as I just start the app... but on executing a request the HttpServletRequest is null.... So I keep on searching for a solution...

Answer (score 0):

For me we had "spring.main.web-application-type=none" mistakenly set in our spring properties file, it shouldn't have been set to none as that was making spring not get the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest bean, resulting in a very similar error to the one you have posted.